# How to referer to findAt list/tuple in abaqus python script

Tags: python, brackets, abaqus

For abaqus i'm writing a script that uses points from different files to create the structure. In order to create a set within abaqus the findAt command is ussed.

```
    db.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].Set(edges=
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].edges.findAt(tensionList), name='Tension')
```

The tensionList:

```
    tensionList = [([0.75, 1.25, 0.0], ()), ([0.25, 0.75, 0.0], ()), ([0.75, 0.25, 0.0], ()), ([0.5, 2.0, 0.0], ()), ([0.0, 1.5, 0.0], ()), ([0.25, 1.75, 0.0], ()), ([1.0, 1.5, 0.0], ())]
```

When running this script in abaqus the following error does occur:

"TypeError: arg1; too many arguments; expected 1, got 7"

However when removing the outer brackets [] from the tensionList and place it directly in the script, the script does work:

```
    mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].Set(edges=
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].edges.findAt(([0.75, 1.25, 0.0], ()), ([0.25, 0.75, 0.0], ()), ([0.75, 0.25, 0.0], ()), ([0.5, 2.0, 0.0], ()), ([0.0, 1.5, 0.0], ()), ([0.25, 1.75, 0.0], ()), ([1.0, 1.5, 0.0], ())), name='Tension')
```

(Script does not work with pasting everything in script with outer brackets [], but also the same error occurs if outer brackets are removed in tensionList and refered to as in example 1)

How could i solve this problem without haveing to copy past everything is. (process will have many iterations and very long lists)

EDIT: Solved by ussing a workaround with edge indexes (still interested how this could have been solved with findAt)

```
    index =0
    while index < (len(compressiveMembersIndex)+len(tensileMembersIndex)):
         mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].Set(edges=
              mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].edges[index:index+1], 
              name=aSetCreating[index])
         index +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an extra set of parentheses in a few places... 
My code below works for me in the format shown, this takes the input as one x,y,z.

```
findAt((x, y, z),)
```

A possible work around for you could be either to make a list of the xyz coords and reference the list using findAt using a loop?

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
z[7,8,9]
edgeslist=[]
numedges=5
    for i in xrange(numedges)
        edgeslist.append( findAt((x[i], y[i], z[i]),) )
```

Alternatively, if your edges lie on a convenient path you could always use findAt to get one edge then use getEdgesByEdgeAngle(...)